# is it true that Λ is a singleton?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

> For $A, B \in 2^{\mathbb{R}}$ and $C \in \mathbb{R}$, define
> $$A+B:=\{x+y:x\in A, y\in B\}\text,$$
> $$cA :=\{cx:x\in A\}\text.$$
> Let $\{I_\alpha\}_{a\in\Lambda}$ be a family of nonempty open intervals which are pairwise disjoint, i.e. $$I_\alpha \cap I_\beta = \varnothing \text{ whenever } \alpha \ne \beta.$$
> Let $$U:=\bigsqcup_{a\in \Lambda} I_\alpha.$$
> Suppose that the index set $\Lambda$ is nonempty and $U+U=2U.$ Show that $\Lambda$ is a singleton.

Comment: Simply repeating your question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3861741/42969 does not make it better.

Comment: To Martin R: Sorry, I don’t understand what you are saying. What do you mean “make it better”? This is the problem that I want to search for help. And I’m afraid that I can’t make it better. Of course, I will more than appreciated if you could help me improve this question

Comment: My guess is your assertion is false since you're being downvoted so much. Try asking a question instead, i.e. "is it true that $\Lambda$ is a singleton?" If it is true someone will answer with a proof, and if it isn't true you'll find out why.

Comment: If your question had been closed, the correct way to proceed is to address the closure reason (either by improving the question to make it acceptable by the standards of the site, or by addressing why this is unnecessary, or why the closure is misguided (e.g. your question is closed as a duplicate, but the duplicate's answers are not helpful)). The entirely wrong way to proceed is to delete your question and post it again.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\Lambda$ is not a singleton for some $U$ such that $U+U = 2U$, then we have two constituent open intervals $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ with $b,c \in \mathbb R$, say $b \leq c$. Note $b \not\in U$, since then the family would not be disjoint.

Lemma: Let $x_n := b+\frac {c-b} {2^n}$. Then each $x_n \in U$.

pf by induction: For n=1, consider that $x_1 - \frac {c-b} {2} = b$ and $x_1 + \frac {c-b} {2} = c$. Thus for small enough $\delta$,
$x_1 - \frac {c-b} {2} - \delta \in (a,b)$ and $x_1 + \frac {c-b} {2} + \delta \in (c,d)$, so $x_1 - \frac {c-b} {2} - \delta+x_1 + \frac {c-b} {2} + \delta = 2x_1 \in U+U = 2U$, so $x_1 \in U$ which establishes the base case.

Now suppose $x_n \in U$. We have $x_{n+1} = b+\frac {c-b} {2^{n+1}} = b+\frac {x_n-b} {2}$. Thus similar to before, $x_{n+1}-\frac {x_n-b} {2} = b$ and $x_{n+1}+\frac {x_n-b} {2} = x_n$. Since $x_n \in U$ and $U$ is open we know there is a $\delta > 0$ such that $x_n+\delta \in U$, and of course this $\delta$ can be chosen small enough for $b - \delta \in (a,b)$. Thus $x_{n+1}-\frac {x_n-b} {2} - \delta + x_{n+1}+\frac {x_n-b} 2 + \delta = 2x_{n+1} \in U+U = 2U$, so $x_{n+1} \in U$. This finishes the proof of the lemma.

Let $v \in (a,b)$, and choose $m$ large enough so that $\frac{c-b}{2^m} < b-v$. Then:

$b < x_m < 2b-v$

$-b > -x_m > v-2b$

$b > 2b-x_m > v > a$ (added $2b$).

Thus both $x_m, 2b-x_m \in U$, which implies $b \in U$. This contradiction shows that the assertion of $\Lambda$ not being a singleton was incorrect, so the proposition is proven.